# How to call an AWS webservice (API Gateway) on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In my iOS project, I need to implement the AWS SDK, as I successfully did in the Android version of that project.

I imported `AWSMobileClient` and `AWSAPIGateway` in my iOS project using Cocoapods.

Here is what I did in my Android project, that I want to replicate on iOS:

- I created an `AWSInterface` interface, where all my api endpoints are:

```
@Service(endpoint = "https://abcde12345.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev")
interface AWSInterface
{
    @Operation(path = "/api-demo", method = "POST")
    fun apiDemo(
        @Parameter(name = "Content-Type", location = "header") contentType: String,
        body: ApiDemoModel): RetourStatutWS
}
```

- and here is the `ApiDemoModel`, very simple:

```
class ApiDemoModel(val code: String)
```

- I created an `AWSInterfaceHolder` class, so I'll be able to call apis:

```
class AWSInterfaceHolder
{
    var awsInterface: AWSInterface = ApiClientFactory()
        .credentialsProvider(AWSMobileClient.getInstance())
        .clientConfiguration(ClientConfiguration().withConnectionTimeout(30000))
        .build(AWSInterface::class.java)
}
```

- I call my api, after a successful initialization of `AWSMobileClient`:

```
// AWSMobileClient is successfully initialized, I can call my api:
val awsInterfaceHolder = AWSInterfaceHolder()
awsInterfaceHolder.awsInterface.apiDemo(
    "application/json",
    ApiDemoModel("123456"))
```

How can I do the same for my iOS Swift project?

Thanks.

Comment: Since this is a swift question you should focus on including swift code so show us what you have written in swift and explain what your issue is with your code. Otherwise it will look like you think this is some free code writing service.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I understand, but that's my point: I don't know where to start...

Comment: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/ios